# Sub nav falling behind elements on site

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I'm running into a small issue with my site's navigation.

```
http://23.235.195.35/~rosemarc/
```

The sub nav under "Services" disappears behind my slider area.

Any thoughts as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a overflow:hidden in the wrapper element. Had nothing to do with z-index. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It's a z-index issue regarding the positions of elements.

See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=z-index and [Understanding z-index](http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp) and  [The Z-Index CSS Property: A Comprehensive Look](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I keep messing around with the z-index of different elements on the site and am still not having any luck with it. Do you think it could be because of the main navigation?